# Safely and cleanly remove mirror stuck with silicone adhesive from wooden frame

Tags: carpentry, mirror, silicone

I have a 27" wide mirror that has been glued with a silicone adhesive on a plywood frame that's about 10mm thick. The height of the mirror is roughly 36". I'm looking for some advice on how I could loosen the glue and remove the mirror from the frame.

Comment: If it is stuck on with silicone there will be nothing clean about the removal, silicone is some of the most contrary stuff to separate, especially in this case a mirror. I have used a strong thin wire, like a piano wire or guitar string to run behind objects and saw them off. If you are wanting to salvage the mirror, this will surely affect the silvering on the back of the mirror.

Comment: if you don't care about the plywood, soak the whole thing in water for several days and you can probably delaminate the mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 feet of braided fishing line, and a couple of dowels for handles, if it's "on" the "frame" - if it's "in" the frame you'll probably have to decide whether you want to salvage the mirror **or** the frame, and destructively remove the other, as getting the line behind it won't be practical, most likely.

Getting the whole thing **very** warm may make cutting it easier.

Comment: Dental floss works for me and most have that if it can be slipped behind the glass then it can work like a saw pulling back and forth, and I also agree nothing will do it clean additional steps to remove the silicone will be needed.

Comment: With great joy, I would like to inform you that the operation was successful. What worked was a combination of WD40 to soften the silicone, braided fishing line, heat from a hair dryer and an important ingredient that I was seriously running low on - patience. Thank you for all the suggestions. I plan to reframe the recovered mirror.